# Having a hard time converting python to JS

Tags: javascript, python, function, math

I am trying to implement the `math.frexp` function in python. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.frexp) if you're confused. Apparently, I am working on [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/write-in-python-wip/5516671889178624) program on Khan Academy.

However, it is PJS and does not support `DataView` or `ArrayBuffer`. Can someone please help me with this implementation this?

Here is the current code (commented out because of `DataView`/`ArrayBuffer`). I found this on the Internet.

```
var frexp = function(value) {
    if (value === 0){
        return [value, 0];
    }
    var data = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8));//Does not support DataView and ArrayBuffer objects.
    data.setFloat64(0, value);
    var bits = (data.getUint32(0) >>> 20) & 0x7FF;
    if (bits === 0) {
        data.setFloat64(0, value * Math.pow(2, 64));
        bits = ((data.getUint32(0) >>> 20) & 0x7FF) - 64;
    }
    var exponent = bits - 1022,
    mantissa = value * Math.pow(2, -exponent);
    return [mantissa, exponent];
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as efficient as reading the bytes

```
exponent = Math.trunc( 1023+Math.log( Math.abs(value) )/Math.LN2 ) - 1022;
mantissa = value * Math.pow(2,-exponent);
```

Should return a pair such that `2^(e-1) <= val < 2^e` and thus `0.5 <= m < 1`.  In ECMA 6 the quotient can be replaced by `Math.log2`.

The floating point evaluation of the logarithm can lead to fuzzy results at dyadic powers. Which may give wrong results where `e=exponent` is one too small. Thus add the line

```
if (Math.abs(mantissa) >=1 ) { exponent +=1; mantissa /=2; }
```

Comment: it is not working. `frexp(1)` should return `[0.5, 1]`; instead, it returns `1, 0`.

Comment: Ok, then you need the exponent one larger. Subtract only 1022 as in your code example. The IEEE double bias is 1023.